# How to display a dialogbox inside a tab control page?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

How do i set another dialogbox visible inside the tab thats currently open in the Tab Control object?

I'm creating the Tab Control in the Visual Studio 2008 resource editor (or how its called?), i created `IDD_FORMVIEW` dialogbox for the tab control.

I know how to initialize the tab texts, handle the currently selected tab with `WM_NOTIFY` message, etc, but what im missing is: how to send the handle of my other dialogbox to the tab control page to display the dialogbox there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the 'tab pages' which are dialogues should be set as children to the tab that is created. When a tab is changed you will get a notify message which you can handle in your DialogProc like this:

```
case WM_NOTIFY: {
    switch( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> code ) {
    case TCN_SELCHANGE: {
      if( TabCtrl_GetCurSel( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> hwndFrom ) == 0 ) {
        ShowWindow( hwndPathSettings, SW_SHOW );
        ShowWindow( hwndStartSettings, SW_HIDE );
      } else {
        ShowWindow( hwndPathSettings, SW_HIDE );
        ShowWindow( hwndStartSettings, SW_SHOW );
      }

      break;
    }
```

As you can see when the user changes the tab, the code shows the new tab child and hides the old ones. hwndPathSettings and hwndStartSettings in this case are the window handles to the child dialogues.

To put it in context, in your WM_INITDIALOG you would probably have some code similar to this to set up the tab:

```
    HWND   hwndTab = GetDlgItem( hwndDlg, IDC_TAB );
    TCITEM tci     = {0};
    tci.mask       = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.pszText    = _T("Path");

    TabCtrl_InsertItem( hwndTab, 0, &tci );

    tci.pszText = _T("Run on Start");
    TabCtrl_InsertItem( hwndTab, 1, &tci );

    hwndPathSettings  = CreateDialogParam( GetModuleHandle( NULL ),
      MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_PATHSETTINGS ), hwndTab, PathSettingsProc, lParam );
    hwndStartSettings = CreateDialog( GetModuleHandle( NULL ),
      MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_STARTSETTINGS ), hwndTab, StartSettingsProc );
    break;
```

Comment: +1, and I suggest to use WTL -- it's a zero-overhead wrapper for windows API.

Comment: nice, the dialogbox changes with this code, but i dont really understand the inconsistent code you used there: how come the first `hwndPathSettings` declaration is using a different function than the second. what function will i use for the third tab? also could you explain what exactly this is supposed to do: `if(TabCtrl_GetCurSel(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom) == 0)` , is it to check which form it changed to? but why its comparing to zero? wouldnt this do it better: `if(TabCtrl_GetCurSel(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TAB2)) == 0)` ..?

Comment: The second block of code is what should be in WM_INITDIALOG. This inserts the pages into the tab control and creates the children. The first block of code is the handler for changing tabs which switches the page contents. There is no need for GetDlgItem when we already have the hwndTab from lParam.

Comment: yes but why does one of the handles get createn with CreateDialogParam() and another with CreateDialog() ? why not both with CreateDialogParam() or CreateDialog() ? i dont understand why is the other more special than the other, thats my point. and how do i determine which one is the more special etc. i dont understand that.

Comment: Ah I see. That is something specific to the code I was doing. The only difference is CreateDialogParam allows you to pass in a parameter. If you have no need to pass anything in you can just use CreateDialog.